# React-native screen does not appear on the iOS simulator using react-native

Tags: android, ios, swift, reactjs, react-native

I am now trying to develop an application with react-native, but the first project does not work well.

### Environment

- cocoapods-1.9.3
- node v10.16.2
- watchman 4.9.0
- Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0

### What I've tried

I did environment setup according to the [official cite](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

```
$ npx react-native init AwesomeProject
$ cd AwesomeProject
$ npx react-native run-ios
```

And I see the iOS screen, but there is no statement like "Welcome to react-native", which should be appeard on the screen.
What I can see on the simulator is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zZjb.png).

When I execute the command

```
$ npx react-native start
```

I can see the react-native logo like this,

```
               ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               

                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere



To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

but under there is a warning statement.

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Reloading app...
```

How can I get the simulator screen like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSGZJ.png) which is shown as a success result?

Comment: Did U solve this? Each start command needs to run in its own terminal. And the `ios-start` can take like 10 mins to build before you will see the react screen.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npx react-native start` inside your React Native project folder:
Then run `npx react-native run-ios`. Wait metro bundler started then run this command

Another way try expo version solution from documentation or read carefully React Native CLI Quickstart solution.